# Person Life Event

Tags: financial-services-cloud

I am working on life Events in FSC.I have installed Finserv managed packag.
In my sandbox org I see Personal Life Events object, while in dev I see 
FinServ__LifeEvent__c.how can i Enable personal Life events.does anyone have any idea.

Comment: FinancialForce and Financial Services Cloud are different products. Please make sure to tag only the relevant one.

Answer (score 0):

well my api versions were different in both th orgs thats why i was not able to do it.person life event is part of new release